# append .composer/vendor/bin permanently to $PATH:$HOME

Tags: laravel, terminal, composer-php

Rather than appending the folder `.composer/vendor/bin` for a terminal session, I'd like to permanently move to `$PATH:$HOME` for continuous use rather than having to run  `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` in terminal when I want to create a new project with *composer* or *laravel*.

What are the steps to do this?

> `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` This appends the folder
>   to your existing PATH, however, it is only active for your current
>   terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to e.g. your `.profile`:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

and logout and login again. This will make the `$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin` folder pemanently added to your `$PATH`.

Comment: On Linux, it is in your home directory (`~/.profile`).

Comment: im on a mac. I put in ~/.bash_profile but it didnt work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Mac, so I can't provide any details.

Comment: Did you start a new terminal session after editing the `.bash_profile` file?

Comment: I did but it still didn’t work. When I type “laravel” in terminal the command is not found.